# I have an error in my program that python detected. Plus im sure there are more errors. Please fix ^-^

Tags: python, python-2.7

My program:

```
import random
from random import randint
print "Welcome to fishing game!"
tries = 3
Fish = []
Fishlist = ["Shark", "Whale", "Boot", "Nothing"]
Money = 0
randomfishvar = (random.choice(Fishlist))
def randomnum100():
    randomnum100 =(randint(1, 100))
    print randomnum100
    Money = Money + randomnum100
    print str(Money) + "$"
def randomnum75():
    randomnum75 = (randint(1, 75))
    print randomnum75
    Money = Money + randomnum75
    print str(Money) + "$"
def randomnum50():
    randomnum50 = (randint(1, 50))
    print randomnum50
    Money = Money + randomnum50
    print str(Money) + "$"
def randomnum25():
    randomnum25 = (randint(1, 25))
    print randomnum25
    Money = Money + randomnum25
    print str(Money) + "$"
def randomnum0():
    randomnum = 0
    print randomnum
    Money = Money + 0
    print str(Money) + "$"
dowhat = raw_input("Tries, Fish, Money, Gofish? ")
if dowhat.lower() == "tries":
    print "You currently have " + str(tries) + " tries."
if dowhat.lower() == "fish":
    print Fish
if dowhat.lower() == "money":
    print str(Money) + "$"
if dowhat.lower() == "gofish":
    print randomfishvar
    Fish.append(randomfishvar)
    if randomfishvar == "Nothing":
        randomnum0()
        Fish.remove("Nothing")
    if randomfishvar == "Shark":
        randomnum75()
    if randomfishvar == "Whale":
        randomnum100()
    if randomfishvar == "Boot":
        randomnum25()
```

It gave me an error like this: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 52, in 
    randomnum25()
  File "***", line 27, in randomnum25
    Money = Money + randomnum25
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Money' referenced before assignment

How can I fix this?
+
Could you please detect any other errors that I could fix? Because python wont detect any other error until I fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic scope problem. Nonlocal variables by default have read-only access in functions, assignment to a variable with the same name as a variable outside of the function will result in a new, empty, local variable being created.

Adding a `global Money` line at the top of each function that is supposed to manipulate the data in the nonlocal Money variable would be a possible workaround. Arguably cleaner would be to pass the variable as a parameter to the function.

Also, while your sequences of `if`s with mutually exclusive conditions are not logically faulty per se, they are not clean code as they result in a lot of unnecessary checks being made. Try to use `elif` in this case.

Also, in future, if you have the audacity to plainly ask other people to "fix" your code for you, it would be nice to at least give a short explanation of what you would expect it to do if it was working.

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. I have a course on udemy and my latest lecture was about scopes. Didnt really get anything and said will study it later. + thanks for the advice!

Comment: @AbdullaAlzaabi Happy to help :) I'd appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted then.